# Is there an easier way to detect collision on an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision-detection, collision

Are there any easier ways for 2D collision detection between images and shapes on an HTML canvas? I'm tired of typing the following if statement every time I want to detect collision.

```js
if (a.x < b.x + b.width && a.x + a.width > b.x && a.y < b.y + b.height && a.y + a.height > b.y) {
    // rectangle a and rectangle b are colliding
}
```

Plus, this algorithm can only detect collision between 2 rectangles, not 2 circles or a circle and a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any libraries that I know of that are specifically built for 2d collision, but if you want to check out a cool 2d physics library check out matter.js, other wise if you don't want to use a whole library, check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection. If you are working on making a platformer, you should check out these platformer physics I made in javascript: https://platformerphysics.netlify.app.